# Run a shell command through a Chrome App

Tags: shell, google-chrome-app, chromebook, crouton-os

*I have Crouton on my Chromebook with Spotify inside an Ubuntu chroot.
I can execute Spotify inside an Ubuntu chroot as a single app window via a Crouton command.*

I want to create a Chrome OS application that acts as a launcher for Spotify, Skype, etc.

**In short:**
My Chrome OS app should execute a shell command.

I read about NPAPI, but it says it's getting depreciated (since 2013 o.O).

If there's another way (for example executing a bash script that adds a button to the shelf that just executes another shell script to open Spotify), it would also be great.

Thx in advance :)

**EDIT:**

With Dart this seems to be possible. It says "access File system, USB Devices, shells and much more" with it

Comment: Please try something...

Comment: I just have no idea what i should be doing ...

All API's and things i want to use are depreciated :(

I'll try to get a desktop installation running with a Dart IDE. Maybe that works

Comment: Dart only forwards to Chrome JS API calls. If you can do it in Dart, you can do it in JS (this applies only for browser apps).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) is just the thing you're looking for! However you may need to create an application that can be registered as a Native Messaging Host. This application will then in turn call the shell command/script you intend to run.